# is there a way to set the window size in Ghost.py?

Tags: python, ghost.py

Back in selenium+phantomjs there were a function called set_window_size, and for a project I am working on is very useful, there is a way to do something similar with Ghost.py? I have searched the documentation and found nothing about it.

If is any helpful I am working on Arch, with python 3 and with PySide.

______Update___________________________________________________

Thanks for the answers! I was able to do that with most sites, the problem came when I was trying to take a capture from Google Maps with ghost.py...it just don't work. If I use the display option I am able to change the horizontal size, but just that.

At the end, I a used phanthomjs script: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

And I did could take a picture of a google maps place. It is strange the behavior of ghost.py.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the attribute `viewport_size` for ghost.Session() it is a tuple to set the initial size, hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that is the way, thank you.
But for some reason it does not work for me. Do you have any idea what could it be? The example I am using is:

'with ghost.start(viewport_size=(1024, 1024)) as session:
  page, extra_resources = session.open(url);
  ts = time.time();
  name = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S');
  time.sleep(5);
  #driver.save_screenshot(path+name+'.jpg');
  session.capture_to(name+".jpg",region=None, selector=None);'